# Will using an API without the capabilities cause my app to terminate or just throw an exception?

Tags: .net, exception, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm working on a piece of code that tries to get as much information as possible from a users device on Windows Phone 8. I noted this quote in certification guidelines

> Your app may close unexpectedly if it tries to access an API that it
>   does not have the security capability to use. For more information
>   about how to work with security capabilities, see How to determine app
>   capabilities.

So, what exactly does that mean? For example this code:

```
try
{
  SomeInfo=SomeFunctionThatRequiresACapability();
}
catch
{
 //oh well, I guess we can't get that piece of info. ignore it
}
```

Would this probably certify? Or do I need to check that we have the capability first?

Comment: This is impossible to miss when you test your code.  It is not randomly going to not throw sometimes, you don't get a capability you didn't ask for.  So don't add that try/catch, it is useless.  Either tick the capability or remove the code.

Comment: @HansPassant this is a library which other people would put in their own phone applications. We really would like to avoid the whole "use this version if you have this capability" type stuff

Answer (score 0):

If you don't add the capabilities, it'll throw a exception at runtime. However, it won't certify, as the XapValidation tool checks your compiled code, not your list of capabilities in a xml file.

Comment: The XapValidation tool which ships with Visual Studio (store test kit) checks compiled code? I've just never had it fail so I figured it didn't do much

Comment: The exception to this, in my experience, is the web browser capability. The XapValidation can miss it and will push your app through without the capability - causing an exception to be thrown at runtime. I worked around it by creating a `WebBrowser` field on my App class.

Comment: That's not true. For example, in my experience, using the Geolocation service with an app that does not have the permission to use it may simply result in the app hanging indefinitely.

Comment: No, I meant the internal XapValidation tool, which we **don't** ship ;-)